# Use ShellExecute to run icacls with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, cmd, shellexecute, cacls

I am trying to execute icacls from c++. Code below does nothing. I still don't know why it does nothing. I cannot see what icacls return to me because cmd windows automactly closes. HINSTANCE also doesnt provides me much. How i can use icacls with multiple parameters?

```
HINSTANCE hInst = ShellExecute( NULL, 
NULL,  
L"icacls",  
L"s.jpg /grant:r %username%:W",     
L"C:/",    
SW_NORMAL 
);
```

Comment: You're not writing a batch file. Maybe you'd be better off calling the proper Win32 APIs?

Comment: Using win32 Apis is harder than you think. Tried it also but couldnt do much there also.

Comment: Did you check `hInst` to see if you are getting an error? If the function succeeds, it returns a value greater than 32.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lpFile` parameter probably should be `"icacls.exe"` with an `.exe` extension.

Also, you should always check for errors.  If `ShellExecute()` succeeds, it returns a value greater than 32. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a list of error codes that may be returned.

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes, you can look at the output from `icacls` by wrapping it in `cmd /k`:

```
HINSTANCE hInst = ShellExecute( NULL,
    NULL,
    L"cmd",
    L"/k icacls s.jpg /grant %username%:W",
    L"C:/",
    SW_NORMAL
);
```

[Why `grant:r`?]

Answer (score 0):

Undeleting post:

I had written up this bit of code earlier, unfortunately it is CLR/.NET specific. However, since you professed that using 'the API' is hard (it is, I did it 10 years ago and NTFS ACLS are no picknick), you might be motivated by the below sample to integrate a bit of .NET code (C++/CLI or Interop based?)

---

Any specific reason not to use C# code?

```
AddFileSecurity(fileName, @"DomainName\AccountName",
        FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);

RemoveFileSecurity(fileName, @"DomainName\AccountName",
        FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

With the following helpers from [MSDN: How to: Add or Remove Access Control List Entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229078.aspx):

```
public static void AddFileSecurity(string fileName, string account,
        FileSystemRights rights, AccessControlType controlType)
{
    FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);
    fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
                rights, controlType));
    File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);
}

public static void RemoveFileSecurity(string fileName, string account,
        FileSystemRights rights, AccessControlType controlType)
{
    FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);
    fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
                rights, controlType));
    File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);
}
```

See the article for full details and comments